# Failed to display Chinese texts in manim animation even after trying to change the value of TEX_USE_CTEX

Tags: python, animation, utf-8, latex, manim

Basically it is the same issue as in https://github.com/3b1b/manim/issues/570, however it was not clear how the person solved the issue, for he stated that he didn't know how he managed to solve it. I am using Windows 10 and MiKTeX. 
I tried to edit `constants.py`,`TEX_USE_CTEX = False` was changed to `True` and it returns the error:

```
File "D:\Programs\manim\manim\manimlib\extract_scene.py", line 153, in main
    scene = SceneClass(**scene_kwargs)
  File "D:\Programs\manim\manim\manimlib\scene\scene.py", line 54, in __init__
    self.construct()
  File "tutorial/1_text_format.py", line 5, in construct
    text = TextMobject("你好")
  File "D:\Programs\manim\manim\manimlib\mobject\svg\tex_mobject.py", line 144, in __init__
    self, self.arg_separator.join(tex_strings), **kwargs
  File "D:\Programs\manim\manim\manimlib\mobject\svg\tex_mobject.py", line 45, in __init__
    self.template_tex_file_body
  File "D:\Programs\manim\manim\manimlib\utils\tex_file_writing.py", line 19, in tex_to_svg_file
    dvi_file = tex_to_dvi(tex_file)
  File "D:\Programs\manim\manim\manimlib\utils\tex_file_writing.py", line 67, in tex_to_dvi
    "See log output above or the log file: %s" % log_file)
Exception: Xelatex error converting to xdv. See log output above or the log file: D:\Programs\manim\manim\manimlib\files\Tex\6d518d13918960fc.log
```

And the command is extremely simple:

```
class WriteText(Scene): 
    def construct(self): 
        text = TextMobject("你好")
        self.play(Write(text))
        self.wait(3)
```

Any methods that were proven to work to solve the issue? For I am not the first one encountering this.

Edit: 
It is what it says in `D:\Programs\manim\manim\manimlib\files\Tex\6d518d13918960fc.log`.

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999992 (MiKTeX 2.9.7400 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2020.5.4)  4 MAY 2020 05:14
entering extended mode
**D:/Programs/manim/manim/manimlib/files/Tex/6d518d13918960fc.tex
(D:/Programs/manim/manim/manimlib/files/Tex/6d518d13918960fc.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-04-06>)
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...nim/manimlib/files/Tex/6d518d13918960fc.tex

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 18 strings out of 414218
 562 string characters out of 2903153
 244959 words of memory out of 3000000
 17616 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 532338 words of font info for 24 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 1348 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 12i,0n,15p,95b,8s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s

No pages of output.
```

Comment: What does D:\Programs\manim\manim\manimlib\files\Tex\6d518d13918960fc.log say?

Comment: Please see the edited question. I just added the content of the log file.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like something strange is going on. Is there a file D:\Programs\manim\manim\manimlib\files\Tex\6d518d13918960fc.tex ?

Comment: Yes there is, but it's completely empty.

Comment: Ah, that explains the strange log file. This means it's not a tex problem and I can't help, sorry!

Comment: Alright, thanks for your effort and help anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can check if your MiKTeX is "Complete version" instead of "Basic version". You can delete it completely and then install it again, make sure to select "Complete version". If you still meet this bug, try using TeX Live. Just click this link https://matnoble.me/tech/ubuntu/install-texlive/ and find how to install it on Windows.